Where to find the Expectation Values of Aspect's and Clauser Experiments
Alain Aspect and John Clauser won the Nobel Prize in Physics for their epxeriments on quantum entanglement. Does anyone know where to find the raw data or at least published calculated expectation values of their findings? I can't find them on their publications or anywhere else in the literature. I am trying to gain deeper understanding of quantum entanglement. Thank you!
J

duplicate of this now closed post of a week ago.  Thus: same comment.  You will have to ask te authors.

If you want to gain more understanding of entanglement, the raw data is the last thing you should seek. How about reading their papers? And I would recommend the newer works by Zeilinger over those of Clauser or Aspect, simply because their accuracy is much higher and the language is much cleaner. Try reading this, which is practically a primer on entanglement experiments: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810080 Freebee hint: read reference [17] once you understand the main paper.
